# ¿Como puedo pasar un diccionario a un array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista de coordenadas en las cuales quiero pasar a un array con sus respectivas distancias. Diccionario de ejemplo:

```
my_diccionario = {1: (228.0, 149.0), 2: (288.0, 129.0), 3: (270.0, 133.0), 4: (256.0, 141.0), 5: (256.0, 157.0), 6: (246.0, 157.0), 7: (236.0, 169.0), 8: (228.0, 169.0), 9: (228.0, 161.0), 10: (220.0, 169.0)}
```

Ocupo obtener las distancias de cada nodo con respecto a los demas, de una manera que quede asi. **Este paso ya lo hice**

```
Saque las distancias de cada nodo con el nodo que puede visitar y lo guarde en un diccionario
distancia_nodos = 
{(1, 2): 63.245553203367585,
 (1, 3): 44.94441010848846,
 (1, 3): 29.120439557122072,
 (1, 5): 29.120439557122072,
 (1, 6): 19.697715603592208,
 (1, 7): 21.540659228538015,
 (1, 8): 20.0,
 (1, 9): 12.0,
 (1, 10): 21.540659228538015,
 ..... }
```

Ahora lo que quiero es convertir mi diccionario "distancia_nodos" a un array de manera que quede:

```
    1                       2              3           ........
1  0.0                   (su valor)     (su valor)
2  63.245553203367585      0.0          (su valor)
3  29.120439557122072    (su valor)       0.0
....
```

No se si se pueda de esta manera o haya alguna otra más sencilla. Un ejemplo de la matriz final seria el siguiente. **Solo que con valores decimales**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por dar un ejemplo completo y reproducible, voy a restringir el diccionario de entrada a un caso más pequeño en el que los índices pueden variar sólo entre 1 y 5. Así por ejemplo:

```
data = {
 (1, 2): 41.07526549507096,
 (1, 3): 22.856273636452784,
 (1, 4): 3.492304410229785,
 (1, 5): 52.04295473094091,
 (2, 1): 82.79636513850231,
 (2, 3): 56.45025932658161,
 (2, 4): 42.586844294457215,
 (2, 5): 0.6176184454665057,
 (3, 1): 42.47635190951639,
 (3, 2): 15.929481717543537,
 (3, 4): 4.99535780261442,
 (3, 5): 4.966241193473775,
 (4, 1): 84.30270471948866,
 (4, 2): 29.89401360904744,
 (4, 3): 59.546460210208586,
 (4, 5): 38.87451444668978,
 (5, 1): 44.65871870466776,
 (5, 2): 19.13768246985952,
 (5, 3): 73.92331745046285,
 (5, 4): 71.85079733713738
}
```

La forma más sencilla de convertirlo a una matriz como la que buscas es crear un array numpy relleno de ceros, con las dimensiones correctas (5 por 5 en este caso), y luego ir recorriendo todos los items de tu diccionario, para extraer de cada clave las coordenadas x,y del elemento del array, y del valor el dato a asignar. Ten cuidado no obstante con un detalle: los elementos del array se numeran desde 0, pero los nodos de tu problema parecen numerarse desde 1.

Lo que propongo sería entonces:

```
import numpy as np

size = 5
matriz = np.zeros((size, size))
for (x, y), v in data.items():
  matriz[x-1,y-1] = v
```

Y la matriz resultante saldría:

```
array([[ 0.        , 41.0752655 , 22.85627364,  3.49230441, 52.04295473],
       [82.79636514,  0.        , 56.45025933, 42.58684429,  0.61761845],
       [42.47635191, 15.92948172,  0.        ,  4.9953578 ,  4.96624119],
       [84.30270472, 29.89401361, 59.54646021,  0.        , 38.87451445],
       [44.6587187 , 19.13768247, 73.92331745, 71.85079734,  0.        ]])
```

Si quieres que se vea más parecido a la imagen que pones al final, puedes usar `pandas` para crear un DataFrame. Podemos aprovechar para "renombrar" las columnas para que vayan de 1 a 5 (en vez de 0 a 4) y lo mismo con el índice (los nombres de las filas). Así:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(matriz, columns=range(1,size+1))
df.index = range(1,size+1)
```

El Dataframe resultante es:

[image: df]